# Malicious code vulnerability - Field should be package protected. How to fix this sonar issue?

Tags: java, logging, sonarqube

In my class I have logger like

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Myclass.class);
```

While running sonar qube I am getting error like:

> Malicious code vulnerability - Field should be package protected-
>   A mutable static field could be changed by malicious code or by accident. The field could be made package protected to avoid this vulnerability.

How to fix this?

Comment: If this is the real line where you get the warning, Sonar is drunk...

Comment: Please check the message again if this _is really_ the line where the error occurs as the error message and the line you show seem to be independent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mark it as a false positive. Here is a description of how to do this:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Reviewing+Issues#ReviewingIssues-Markinganissueasfalsepositive